# How to show an alert when i press facebook like button in my webpage. asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook

I need to show an alert box when I click the facebook like button. I have tried some scripts but it doesn't work.

Here is the Button Code.

```
    <div class="fb-like" 
   data-href="https://www.facebook.com/uefachampionsleague/?fref=ts
   data-layout="standard" 
   data-action="like"
   data-show-faces="true" 
   data-share="false">
   </div>
```

And I have tried doing with

```
    <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                status: true, 
                cookie: true, 
                xfbml: true  
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
            alert('You liked');
            });
        };
    </script>
 </div>
```

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2010 (just in case).

Comment: $('.fb-like').click(function(){alert('clicked fb like button'); });

Comment: thank you @shalini for your response, but this is also not working.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I wanted to capture that event to perform another operation. but now its done.
          ` <script type="text/javascript">
           FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
           alert('You have liked our page')
          });`